# Understanding INTERLEAVE in Cloud Spanner INDEX (indices)

Tags: database, indexing, database-design, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

What is difference between

```
CREATE INDEX SongsBySingerSongName 
          ON Songs(SingerId, SongName),
          INTERLEAVE IN Singers
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX SongsBySingerSongName 
          ON Songs(SingerId, SongName)
```

Answer (score 6):

Cloud Spanner will interleave the indexes entries in with the data table.

This means the SongsBySingerSongName index entries for each SingerId are colocated together.

From [Spanner > Documentation > Data Definition Language](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/data-definition-language#create-index) :

> Like interleaved tables, entries in an interleaved indexes are stored
>   with the corresponding row of the parent table. See [database splits](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-and-data-model#database-splits)
>   for more details.

and

> **When should you create an interleaved index?** If the index key that you
>   want to use for index operations matches the key of a table, you might
>   want to interleave the index in that table if the row in the table
>   should have a data locality relationship with the corresponding
>   indexed rows.